# Past Tatort episodes with subtitles?

Tags: resource, online-resource

I can't follow most of the dialogue in Tatort, but the German subtitles I can understand almost completely.

Past episodes of Tatort are easy to find online, but the only ones I've found that have subtitles are those shown at [www.ardmediathek.de](http://www.ardmediathek.de).

Does anyone know how to get past Tatort episodes with subtitles?  Alternatively, does anyone know where I can get *just* the subtitles for past Tatort episodes?  (At the moment I'm interested only in subtitles German.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Crazy as it may sound, you could buy the series on DVD, since they usually provide subtitles.

Now, as you can imagine, unofficial subtitles may be considered illegal. As discussed [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/are-unofficial-anime-subtitles-illegal) (SE Meta Anime) and [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/is-it-legal-to-translate-movie-subtitles) (SE Law), “Subtitles are treated much like movie scripts by most video industries” and therefore StackExchange is not a good platform for this question to be asked.

That being said, and the legal question not fully answered, the subtitles for some episodes of Tatort may be found [on this website](http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/ssearch/sublanguageid-all/idmovie-55143).

Expanding my answer a little: You might also find what you are looking for [here](http://subscene.com/subtitles/title?q=tatort&l=), [here](http://subsmax.com/subtitles-movie/tatort) and [here](http://www.seedsu.com/search/?q=tatort).

Answer (score 5):

The official website let's you stream recent episodes with (German) subtitles.
https://www.daserste.de/unterhaltung/krimi/tatort/videos

Comment: This streaming may be unavailable from outside Germany, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some subtitles files (srt) at [opensubtitles.org](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search2/sublanguageid-all/moviename-tatort). Approximatively 50 files.